# All the $m$th powers commute with each other and all the $n$th powers commute with each other, $m$ and $n$ relative prime, is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Show that a group in which all the $m$th powers commute with each other and all the $n$th powers commute with each other ,$m$ and $n$ relatively prime, is abelian.

How to do this ? we know $1=mx+yn$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

$ab=a^{mx}a^{ny}b^{yn}b^{mx}=a^{mx}b^{yn}a^{ny}b^{mx}$

but now how to switch $b^{yn}$ and $a^{mx}$ ??

Comment: Found immediately in an https://approach0.xyz search.

Comment: take inverses to show those of powers $|m-n|$ commute.  Then the proof parallels the proof of Bezout's lemma precisely.